# Kendo UI grid filter autofocus

Tags: grid, kendo-ui, autofocus

When using Kendo grids, opening the filter options will give the first operator focus. I understand this I useful when there is multiple operators but I only allow the contains operator so would like the first value box to have focus.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the filter options:

- Add extra: false
- Define only the operators you want

Code example:

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    height: '240px',
    columns: [
        { field: 'Id' },
        { field: 'Number', title: 'Employee #' },
        { field: 'First', title: 'FirstName' },
        { field: 'LastName', title: 'LastName' },
        {
            field: 'FunctionCode', title: 'Function', filterable: {
                extra: false,
                operators: {
                    string: {
                        eq: "Is equal to",
                        neq: "Is not equal to"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

See Kendo UI Grid running demo [here](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/filter-menu-customization.html).
And see [this](http://kendogridbinderex.apphb.com/Employee) page for an example.